# Ruby Regular Expression - prevent overlapping matches

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have a tag `<tag>` and I want to match groups of `<tag>...<tag>` in my string.  I can use a regular expression along the lines of `<tag>.*<tag>`.  This matches `<tag>foo<tag>`, which is good, but it also matches `<tag>foo<tag>bar<tag>`, which is behavior I don't want.  I want the `<tag>foo<tag>` to be matched, then `bar` to be excluded, and then the tag on the end to be the start of the next match.  How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have any HTML string ?

Comment: It's not necessarily HTML - `<tag>` can be substituted for any sequence.

Comment: Any repeating sequence is going to quickly show a downside of using regular expressions, and your job of concocting a pattern that avoids collisions/overlaps will sky-rocket. *IF* you are working with HTML or XML, don't bother with regex if your needs are anything beyond the least trivial use. Instead, use a parser like Nokogiri. Your brain will thank you later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a lazy [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) where the `?` forces the `.*` to match as *few* characters as possible (and not as *many* as possible, as the unadorned `.*` will try to match):

```
<tag>.*?<tag>
```

A safer, more explicit solution is to use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
<tag>(?:(?!<tag>).)*<tag>
```

While in the current case, there is no difference in behavior, the second one is extendable to handle open/close tags, making sure that nested tags aren't incorrectly matched:

```
<tag>(?:(?!</?tag>).)*</tag>
```

when applied to `<tag>foo<tag>bar</tag>baz</tag>` will match `<tag>bar</tag>`, and not `<tag>foo<tag>bar</tag>` as a solution with a lazy quantifier would.

Comment: Can you explain what makes it "safer"?

Answer (score 2):

You use a lazy version of `.*` being:

```
<tag>.*?<tag>
       ^
```

The `?` makes the `.*` match up to until the first match of `<tag>`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - wouldn't `?` just be redundant since `.*` means zero or more of any character?

Comment: @Kvass Here, `?` acts as a 'modifier' and not '0 or 1 times'. `.*?` is said to be 'lazy' while `.*` is said to be 'greedy'.